# How to pass data to component with one way binding only / without binding at all in ember?

Tags: ember.js, ember.js-component

In a template, I am calling component as:

```
{{comp-name data=controllerData}}
```

If I change the data in component, controller's `controllerData` also getting changed due to implicit two way binding. I have two questions:

1) How to make it as one way binding. So that only changes from controller's `controllerData` propagate to component's data.

2) There should be no binding at all. Means, if I change data in either component or controller. It should not reflect in other thing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1) Use the `readonly` helper:

```
{{comp-name data=(readonly controllerData)}}
```

2) Use the `unbound` helper:

```
{{comp-name data=(unbound controllerData)}}
```

See http://emberup.co/bindings-with-htmlbars-helpers/ for more information.

In future versions of Ember with angle bracket components, bindings will be one way by default and you will need to use the `mut` helper to make it two way.

Comment: Hi Gaurav, thanks for the answer. And yes it works for normal property (like, controllerData : "something")

But if it is a json data, seems not working. say, controllerData : { key : "value" }

If i set like:

this.set('controllerData.key', 'someotherthing');
It changes in controller also.

Comment: Yes, that is correct and expected. If you want something like that to work, you will have to use an immutable library like Facebook's immutable.js or seamless-immutable. The binding of the reference to the object is one way but if the object itself is mutable, its changes get propagated.

Answer (score 0):

This article in the guides should help:

https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.18.0/object-model/bindings/

It gives this example:

```
import EmberObject, { computed } from '@ember/object';
import Component from '@ember/component';
import { oneWay } from '@ember/object/computed';

user = EmberObject.create({
  fullName: 'Kara Gates'
});

UserComponent = Component.extend({
  userName: oneWay('user.fullName')
});

userComponent = UserComponent.create({
  user: user
});

// Changing the name of the user object changes
// the value on the view.
user.set('fullName', 'Krang Gates');
// userComponent.userName will become "Krang Gates"

// ...but changes to the view don't make it back to
// the object.
userComponent.set('userName', 'Truckasaurus Gates');
user.get('fullName'); // "Krang Gates"
```

Hope that helps.